# swig unable to find openssl conf

Tags: python, ubuntu, openssl, swig, m2crypto

Trying to install m2crypto and getting these errors, can anyone help ?

```
SWIG/_evp.i:12: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'
SWIG/_ec.i:7: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing M2Crypto 0.20.1 on Python 2.6 on Ubuntu 14.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895210/installing-m2crypto-0-20-1-on-python-2-6-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl/opensslconf.h /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
```

Just made this and everything worked fine.

Comment: You also need to install `libssl-dev` first for this to work.

Answer (score 14):

Installing `libssl-dev` (which contains development libraries, header files) will solve the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: This was the solution for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5):

This was a bug in `M2Crypto`, fixed in at least `0.25.1`. The particular commit is [ecc678d52e6525f9e3278a7cedfa110a64244937](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/commit/ecc678d52e6525f9e3278a7cedfa110a64244937).

Comment: I still get the same error even with `0.25.1`

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS or RHEL, run the following to install OpenSSL development libraries and headers:

```
# yum install openssl-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

[@gordon33](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31861876/462370) reply is good, but if you don't have root (e.g. Travis-CI), you can also add option to pip install that will tell it to pass the options to build environment and compiler options:

`pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu" m2crypto`