# How to provide include path to SWIG?

Tags: python, openssl, swig, setup.py, m2crypto

I'm trying to build M2Crypto library, but `swig` does not find header files:

```
M2Crypto@(master=)$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'M2Crypto.__m2crypto' extension
swigging SWIG/_m2crypto.i to SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c
swig -python -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include -includeall -modern -builtin -outdir build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/M2Crypto -o SWIG/_m2crypto_wrap.c SWIG/_m2crypto.i
SWIG/_evp.i:12: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'
SWIG/_ec.i:7: Error: Unable to find 'openssl/opensslconf.h'
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

I have OpenSSL headers, including `openssl/opensslconf.h`, in `/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu` - that is where `openssl-dev` package installs them to. This path is not passed to swig; `setup.py` seems to know nothing about it.

Does this look like a bug (or a problem) with the package, i.e. M2Crypto? What is the proper fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing M2Crypto 0.20.1 on Python 2.6 on Ubuntu 14.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895210/installing-m2crypto-0-20-1-on-python-2-6-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that libssl-dev moved opensslconf.h into an architecture dependent subtree /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu. Dependent on your architecture, the directory may be different.

There are two possible workarounds (either will work):

Option 1: Softlink the file to where it had been before the change:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl/opensslconf.h /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
```

This is also described in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762106/swig-unable-to-find-openssl-conf)

Option 2: In setup.py of M2Crypto, add the architecture specific directory to the include path used by the swig command:

```
-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

This is also described in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895210/installing-m2crypto-0-20-1-on-python-2-6-on-ubuntu-14-04)

There is also [issue 69](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/issues/69) open for this, in the M2Crypto project.

Andy